# update labels when the text box is updated

Tags: c#, windows

I made a small calculator and i need to make the labels update when textbox is changed ,
and want some help to do that
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the TextChanged event of the TextBox and apply your logic and label setting there

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      lable1.Text = "Xyz";
}
```